# Why « au mois de X » but « en X »?

Tags: prépositions, en, au

All months of the year are masculine, as is the word « mois ». Why don’t they all use the same preposition?

> ✅ Je suis née **en** septembre.
> ✅ Je suis née **au** mois de septembre.
> ❌ Je suis née **au** septembre (??)

Comment: The choice of a preposition has nothing to do with gender. There's no article (the way to show gender) after ***en*** (*en septembre, en avion, en ligne*...), and with *au mois de* ( used when wanting to be more specific) ***au*** is before *mois* and it is ***au*** (*à le*) because *mois* is masculine, nothing to do with the name of the month. But I'm not sure I understood your question, do you want to know the difference between *au mois de [nom du mois]* and *en [nom du mois]* or are you confused between the name of the thing (name of the month) and the signifier (concept of month).

Comment: @None ‘The choice of a preposition has nothing to do with gender’, then can i say « je suis né(e) an mois de septembre »?

Comment: Non, je suis né ***au** mois de septembre* ( *à* required here – *au* is *à le* – , you can't use ***e**n*). But in front of just the name of the month you have to use *en* and no definite article after *en*. A list a French prepositions and when to use them : https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/prepositions/

Comment: @None but why can’t i say **en** le mois de *x*? why is it **au** mois de *x*?

Comment: We cannot have the masculine definite article *le* (and *les*, *du* or *des*) after *en*.   As @jlliagre writes in their answer "You need to conform to usage", it is something that cannot be done, consider it as a rule.  If you want to use a definite article then you must use a different preposition (*au* (→*à le*). The singular feminine definite article is allowed : [*Il y a péril en la demeure*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9ril_en_la_demeure),  *Je crois en la justice* but *je crois aux fantômes*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

◊ The name of the month (*septembre*) is used **without a definite article**<sup>1</sup>, so we use *en* :

- *Je suis née en septembre*.

and **it is the usage** to express it that way. As @jlliagre writes in their answer "You need to conform to usage", that means having *en* followed by *le* is not done, consider it as a rule.

◊ Usage also says that we do not have the masculine definite article *le* (and *les*, *du* or *des*<sup>2</sup>) after *en*. If you want to use the definite article *le* (*les*, *du* or *des*) then you must use a different preposition.

◊ You cannot use *mois* without the definite article, so, to conform to usage we have to use a different preposition that has the same meaning and that allows the presence of the masculine definite article, that is why we say :

- *Je suis né **au** mois de septembre*.

***au*** standing for *à le*<sup>3</sup>.

◊ Note that the singular feminine definite article is allowed after *en* :

- [*Il y a péril en la demeure*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9ril_en_la_demeure).
- *Je crois **en la** justice*<sup>4</sup>.
  but
- *Je crois **aux** fantômes*.

◊ Online resources:
[How do you use the French preposition 'en'?](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/how-do-you-use-the-french-preposition-en) (*Collins* grammar)
[English translation of 'à'](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/%C3%A0) (*Collins* dictionary)
[English translation of 'en'](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/en) (*Collins* dictionary)
[En](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/en-preposition/) (*Lawless* French)
[À](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/a-preposition/) (*Lawless* French)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> We could consider the name of a month is some sort of proper name and we don't normally have a definite article in front of proper names.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> *du* → *de le* ; *des* → *de les*.</sub>  
<sub><sup>3</sup> *À* meaning "in" in English. But *à* can have several other meanings.  *En* can also have other meanings than the English "in".</sub>
<sub><sup>4</sup> You can also say *Je crois à la justice*, there's a nuance in meaning.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions can't be used arbitrarily. You need to conform to the usage. ***En*** is the only one used when directly preceding a month name.

Je suis né ***en*** juin, (mais fin juin, ***au*** mois de juin).
Je suis né ***un*** mardi.
Je suis né ***en*** 1923.
Je suis né ***au*** XX<sup>e</sup> siècle.
Je suis né ***en*** été, pas ***au*** printemps .
Je suis né ***un*** samedi.
Je suis né ***le*** samedi 23 juin 1923.
Je suis né ***le*** matin du samedi 23 juin 1923.

It's similar with locations:
Je suis né ***à*** Marseille.
Je suis né  ***dans les*** Bouches-du-Rhône, pas ***en*** Corse.

<sub><sub>Note: dates and locations above are fictitious. ;-)</sub></sub>

Comment: but why is it **to the** month of september and **in** september? why the difference? why does « mois » require « au » (« à le ») and the name of the month doesn’t?

Comment: @Min From you comment above I gather you think *à* means *to* in English. If that is the case then you are wrong.  *À* means "to" (*Je vais à Paris*) , but it can mean "in" (*je suis né à Marseille* ), it can mean  "at" (*je suis à la maison*, *je viendrai à 6 heures*),  it can mean "by" (*à cheval*, *à vélo*), ...

Comment: On pourrait ajouter: _**le** matin, je mets mes chaussures_.

Comment: @Frank On ne peut pas, ta phrase ne commence pas par *Je suis né* ! :-) Bon, j'ajoute *Je suis né le matin du [...]*.