# Peut-on considérer que la contraction « au » dans « au mois de » vient de la combinaison « en + le » plutôt que « à + le » ?

Tags: prépositions, en, au

Quand on parle des mois de l'année, on dit:

> ***En** quel mois sommes-nous ?*
> *Nous sommes **en** janvier.*
> *Nous sommes **au** mois de janvier.*

Si on considère ce ***au*** comme la contraction « ***à** + le* », on peut se demander : pourquoi utiliser deux prépositions différentes (***en*** vs ***à***) pour parler d'un même sujet ?

Je vois que quelqu'un a eu [le même doute](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/53757/why-au-mois-de-x-but-en-x) que moi et on a répondu à sa question en disant que la préposition *en* ne doit pas être suivi par un article défini masculin et donc il faut remplacer *en* par *à*.

Cette explication m'a bien aidée, mais je voudrais savoir si c'est possible de le comprendre d'une autre façon :

L'expression originelle : *en le mois de*
La combinaison « *en* + *le* » a été remplacée par *au* en français moderne, comme [pour les noms de pays et les saisons](https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/quelle-preposition-porter-cette-saison#fnref1:Ancr1), selon les règles suivantes :

> en l'N → en N (*e.g. en l'Iran → en Iran, en l'hiver → en hiver*)
> en la N → en N (*e.g. en la France → en France*)
> en le N → au N (*e.g. en le Paraguay → au Paraguay, en le printemps → au printemps*)
> en les N → aux N (*e.g. en les Pays-Bas → aux Pays-Bas*)

Donc l'expression *en le mois de* devient *au mois de*, *au* étant une contraction de « *en + le* » (qui devient maintenant identique à celle de « *à + le* »).

Je voudrais l'expliquer ainsi parce que les expressions concernant les saisons et les mois de l'année font partie d'une même leçon. Donc ce serait peut-être mieux de résoudre deux problèmes (pourquoi ***au** printemps* mais ***en** été* / ***en** hiver* & pourquoi ***au** mois de* mais ***en** quel mois* / ***en** janvier*) avec un même raisonnement.

Alors ce raisonnement serait-il correct ?

Comment: https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/23516/la-syntaxe/les-prepositions/preposition-devant-un-nom/les-prepositions-devant-un-nom-de-saison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C'est bien ça, en tout cas si on adopte un point de vue diachronique. Les contractions de *en* avec les articles définis qui existaient jusqu'au 16e siècle se sont ensuite confondues avec celles de *à* et ne survivent dans leur forme originelle que dans le titre académique "docteur ès X" (où *ès* /ɛ/ est la contraction de *en* et *les* -la prononciation /ɛs/ est une innovation moderne basée sur l'orthographe, le mot devrait rimer avec *les* et *des*)

L'évolution jusqu'au moyen français s'est faite ainsi:

- (à + le) al -> au (d'abord /aw/ puis une diphtongue /aʊ̯/ avant de passer à /ɔʊ̯/ puis à /o/)
- (en + le) el -> eu -> ou/u -> au (j'ai beaucoup de mal a trouver des avis concrets sur la valeur des graphies *ou* ou *u* dans ce cas précis)
- (à + les) als -> as
- (en + les) els -> ès

Une fois que les singuliers sont devenus /o/, des pluriels analogiques ont été formés sur cette base, donnant *aux* pour les deux prépositions contractées.

Cette confusion a eu plusieurs conséquences :

- Là où l'article défini ne s'était pas encore imposé, on a continué à utiliser *en* seul (être en retard, entrer en guerre, etc)
- Là où on utilisait régulièrement un article défini, on a recruté *dans* (jusqu'à alors signifiant surtout "à l'intérieur de") en remplacement de *en*, même si aucune contraction n'était utilisée (dans la plaine, par exemple)
- Dans quelques cas, "au" et "aux" sont conservés mais uniquement dans les contextes où une contraction était possible: au masculine devant consonne et au pluriel dans tous les cas. Autrement la contraction alterne soit avec *en*, soit avec *dans + article*. C'est le cas bien entendu des noms de pays ("aux Pays-Bas" mais "dans les Pays-Bas modernes" ou "dans ces Pays-Bas-là)

Dans le cas particulier des saisons, ce conservatisme a entrainé une innovation: là où la langue médiévale n'aurait utilisé que *en* avec elles, la langue contemporaine utilise le plus souvent à (en automne, mais à l'automne dernier).

Voici quelques attestations que j'ai été chercher dans les corpus DMF (http://zeus.atilf.fr/dmf/):

> Et pour ce ceste goute regne plus en païs qui est chaut et moiste, et **en printemps** qui a ces deux qualitez qu'elle ne fait en autre. ( Barthélémy l’Anglais, Le Livre de proprietés des choses, ca.1372, 112b).

> qu'il ne devroit estre, nous doubtons qu e en la fin de cel yver ne vienge epydimie ou **u printemps** ensivant. (Anonyme, Consultation sur la peste (adaptation B), 1349-1350, 137v). (=au printemps suivant)

> quatre temps de l'an d oibvent estre evacué par saignié, chascun en son temps convenable : le cuer **en printemps**, le foie en esté, la teste en yver et les piés en autonne. (Arnauld de Villeneuve, Le Regime Tresutile et Tresproufitable pour Conserver et Garder la Santé du Corps Humain, 1380, 165).

> Et dit que es corps ou il esconvient saigner, nous devons faire **en primtemps**, c'est assavoir en ver. (Hippocrate, Amphorismes Ypocras, 1362-1363, 86ra). Avec un joli "ès corps" en prime

Pas de trace d'un "à printemps" dans cette recherche

Même constat pour *mois*, qui apparait toujours avec *en* ou ses contractions. Par exemple:

> Et se vous voulés de cest buvrage faire pourvoiance pour toute l'année, prenés **ou mois d'aoust** les choses dessus dictes et en faites pilles a la quantité d'une nois de coudre et les sechiés... (Jean Pitard, Receptaire, ca.1300, 12ra).

> Et laditte mortalité commença **ou mois de janvier** et dura par sept mois et en deux magnieres. (Guy de Chauliac, Grande Chirurgie, 3e quart / 2e tiers du 15e, x).

> La vivent bien aucune fois li enfant né **u mois desus dit**, combien qu'il soient moustrüeus et mal formé, mais entour Grece ne vivent il pas. ((Pseudo)-Aristote, Livre des Problemes de Aristote, ca.1380, 187r).

> Et cil, s'il naiscent, lors ne vivent pas volentiers longuement, mais cil qui atendent **dusques au mois unsime**, pource que li solaus revient lors a son tour, vivent plus longuement. ((Pseudo)-Aristote, Livre des Problemes de Aristote, ca.1380, 187v).

> La demorerent tut l'yver **Jesqes au mois du feverer**, Tant qe tut fuist assemblée Et li lointaigne et li privée. (HERAUT CHANDOS, Vie Prince Noir T., c.1385, 104).

(Dans les deux cas précédent, c'est probablement l'usage de "jusque" qui force la préposition *à*)

> en medecine, Et par luy compillé en la noble université de Montpellier, L'an mil trois cens **ou mois de juing** ainsi comme cy apres s'ensuit. (Bernard de Gordon, Fleur de lys, 1377, 1r).

> Et fut fait ledict petit voulume a Mompellier, L'an mil trois cens **au mois de jung** ainsi comme il s'ensuit. (Bernard de Gordon, Fleur de lys, 1377, 1r).

> Ce fut l'an de nostre seigneur mil .ccc. et trois **ou mois de jullet**. (Bernard de Gordon, Fleur de lys, 1377, 4).

> ...**ou mois de septembre** derrenier passé (CHASTELL., Chron. IV D., c.1461-1472, 34).

> ...le duc de Bourgoingne en ce temps cy avoit conclu de tenir **au mois de may** prochain la feste de son ordre, pour cause que plusieurs d'icellui ordre freres estoient trespasséz. Si voloit, comment que feust, que yceulz deux chevaliers y entrefeussent (CHASTELL., Chron. IV D., c.1461-1472, 273).

> Et a ceste cause, et par l'engin de messire Pierre de Brezé, grant seneschal de Normandie, qui tout conduisoit le fait de la royne, firent François une grant armee **ou mois d'avril** de cest present an, joingz avec eulz Espaignolz et Bretons, pour descendre en Angleterre alencontre de Edouard et en secours de la royne (CHASTELL., Chron. IV D., c.1461-1472, 292).

> ...pour la vendue et délivrance de XXI pièces de sayes, de plusieurs couleurs prises, et achettées **au mois d'aoust CCCC et XI** pour faire une tente (Comptes Lille L., t.1, 1382-1482, 29).

> ...demi XIIe de serviectes fines prinses de lui **ou mois de septembre** **précédent** pour servir d'espices devant MdS (Comptes Lille L., t.1, 1382-1482, 81).

> ...tourez et vervelles d'argent dorées et esmaillées aux nom et armes de MdS que **ou mois de décembre** icellui MS a fait prendre et acheter de lui pour sesdits oyseaulx de loire (Comptes Lille L., t.1, 1382-1482, 192).

> Aux paintres, tailleurs de bois et autres ouvriers, occupez **oudit mois de may** à Bruges, en l'ostel des parmentiers, pour le fait des nopces de MdS (Comptes Lille L., t.1, 1382-1482, 499).

Et j'en passe. Je tiens à préciser que "ou" est très dominant par rapport à "au" dans les corpus.

J'ai trouvé quelques exemples sans article défini, tous dans le même texte:

> Le prieuré de Saint Estienne de la maladerie d'Arquez, à cause dudit prieuré, a en la forest d'Arquez, par le don du roy Philippe, roy de France, regnant l'an mil IIIc et XXIX, **en mois d'avril**, chacun jour deux aasnéez de mort bois vert et sec. (HECTOR DE CHARTRES, Cout. R., 1398-1408, 167).

Bref, tout ça pour dire que, oui, *au* dans "au mois de" vient bien de "en+le mois de". Même d'un point de vue synchronique, "à ce mois de juillet" passe assez mal comparé à "dans ce mois de juillet".